# C# - Saving Custom Configuration

Tags: c#

I need to update a value in one of my custom configuration section in my app.config.  Is there a good example on how to do this?

```xml
<mySection>
    <level1>
        <add data1="444"/>
    </level1>
</mySection>
```

I want to update in 444 to 555 programmatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your configuration is stored in application.exe.config, the following should work.

```
void ModifyLevel1Value(int newValue)
{
    Configuration exeConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    MySection section = (MySection)exeConfiguration.GetSection("mySection");

    // Modify value, or whatever is sensible in your program
    section.LevelsCollection["data1"] = newValue;

    exeConfiguration.Save();
}
```

I'm not sure if this will work for web.config as I have little experience with web apps and their configuration.

This technique will rewrite the configuration file but will not flush any internal configuration file caches.  To force the configuration file to be reloaded (which may not be an issue in your application), you can call the following static method.

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(section);
```

Comment: Will this cause the appdomain to get reloaded? will this cause any issue while the app is running?  This is a console app so I assume it would not be a big deal compared to a web app.

Comment: This will not cause the app domain to be reloaded.  Only the configuration file.  I can't comment on what issues this may cause with your app because I don't know how your app is written.

Answer (score 1):

you could use [linq to xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to find the elements you want to change, you should get an [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) object, change it as you wish, and save.